# Passing two struct arrays as parameters to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

So I have Time structure arrays which contain time in hh,mm,ss format.
I have made a function timeDifference to calculate difference of time in seconds.

In my function how can I pass the arguments as two time structures?

I'm trying to do something like this and getting **implicit declaration of function** error;

```
int timeDifference(struct time T[i], struct time T[j]);
```

T[i], T[j] could be referencing to two time structures T[0] and T[1] as follows:

```
struct time{
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
};

int timeDifference(struct time T[i], struct time T[j]);

int main(){
struct time T[8]; // 9 time structures i.e 9 time values in hh,mm,ss
T[0].hours=2;
T[0].minutes= 00; // T[0]
T[0].seconds=00;

T[1].hours=3;
T[1].minutes=10;  // T[1]
T[1].seconds=00;

timeDifference(T[0], T[1]); Function call in main for evaluating difference

.
.
.
}

int timeDifference(struct time T[i], struct time T[j]) // function for 
                                                     // calculating difference
{
.
.
}
```

I think it uses pointers, I'm new to C hence could anyone suggest any online resources for understanding pointers?
Thank You

Comment: Just because c has pointers doesn't mean you always need them. Here, you don't.

Comment: @EOF, the function is not taking parameters like this, getting errors and warnings, implicit declarations.

Comment: `int timeDifference(struct time a, struct time b)`. Also, make sure the prototype is available to `main()`.

Comment: that works too buddy, but can I pass the array index as parameter? @EOF

Answer (score 1):

You are using a function for which the compiler has not seen a declaration.
You need to declare your function before main, like this:

```
//rest of your code
int timeDifference(struct time T[], struct time T[]);
int main(){
//rest of your code
}
```

Comment: I've already done that buddy , sorry forgot to show ; here in the question at declaration in the beginning @k0staa